# Links not working - Mobile device - modernizr

Tags: html, css, css-animations, modernizr

I'm looking for help as I'm stuck with links not working on mobile device (Safari, iPhone at least).

I'm using code from codrops, it's an elastic dragging animation. I'm looking to add links inside each cards ( `<a>` inside each `li` element).
It seems to work on a computer, but not on a mobile device. The link is shown, you can tap it (click) but it doesn't send you to the destination, it's like it's not working.

I guess it's from the CSS animation or maybe modernizr but I'm really not an expert and I need your help !

Here is a link to the original pen with a link on the first image : https://codepen.io/imromain/pen/gwdRzo

Thank you !

Romain

Comment: what destination are you talking about? i don't see any <a> on html..

Comment: oops, sorry about that, the previous pen links to the original codrops code. 
Here is the one with just a link inside the first <li>, as you can see it works on a computer but not on a mobile device. 
https://codepen.io/imromain/pen/gwdRzo

Comment: i'm sorry.. can you show me the original code where you copied that? because all the js seems minified and it's hard to debug

Comment: Sure, here you can download the source : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/12/elastic-stack-elastic-dragging-interaction/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to open an issue on the [original project on github](https://github.com/codrops/ElastiStack/issues)

Then, the creator might help you better.